# How to create youtube-dl extractors?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, youtube-dl

I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#developer-instructions) to create youtube-dl extractor. It says:

> Have a look at [youtube_dl/extractor/common.py](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py) for possible helper
> methods and a [detailed description of what your extractor should and
> may return](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/7f41a598b3fba1bcab2817de64a08941200aa3c8/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py#L94-L303). Add tests and code for as many as you want.

However, it does not explain how to get different values. For example, in [pluralsight extractor](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/7f41a598b3fba1bcab2817de64a08941200aa3c8/youtube_dl/extractor/pluralsight.py) it is using `_API_BASE`, `_GRAPHQL_EP`, `_GRAPHQL_HEADERS`, `_GRAPHQL_COURSE_TMPL`, `GRAPHQL_VIEWCLIP_TMPL`, `_NETRC_MACHINE` etc.

In [safari extractor](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/safari.py) , it is using `_PARTNER_ID`, `_UICONF_ID`, `kaltura_session`, `video_id`, `reference_id`, `mobj`, `part`, `course_id` etc.

How can I get these values?